# force remove index.php from the codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

This is my codeigniter .htaccess file, I was successful in replacing the index.php with method name. But I want to forcefully remove the index.php from the url i.e if someone add index.php in the url i want to remove it using .htaccess. 
Like=> **`http://localhost/project/index.php/welcome`** to=> **`http://localhost/project/welcome`**

**The project is still under development in xampp.**

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 

    # Enforce NO www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #my url is http://localhost/project
    #RewriteBase /project/
    #set your own
    RewriteBase /project/

    #Redirect if index.php exist to without index.php
    RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$  $1 [R=301,L] 

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks, but this one allows index.php in the url. I want to remove it. when ever someone types **localhost/project/index.php/welcome** i want the htaccess to automatically remove index.php to **localhost/project/welcome**

Comment: You can use both way. Dou you deny index.php in url and only works without index.php?

Comment: Updated! Please try again

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and have a look to [this article](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html).

Comment: sorry it's not what i am looking for. I need to forcefully remove the index.php in the url using .htaccess.

Comment: Yes. I understand. My code is an htaccess code. Where is the problem ?

Comment: I edited my code. But i don't understand why my post doesn't answer to your question.

Comment: it's getting redirected to localhost/xampp :/

Comment: Replace your whole code with mine, just to see what it is happened.

Comment: @Ganesh I'm getting the same problem where it redirects to localhost/xampp, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Ganesh no, I'm good. I figured it out too, but don't use CodeIgniter any more.